# TControlScrollBar Position не соответствует Range

Tags: c++builder, delphi-xe7, c++builder-xe

В документации сказано, что `TControlScrollBar.Range` работает следующим образом:

> Use Position to programmatically scroll the client area of the
>   associated control. The value of Position changes (from 0 to Range) at
>   runtime as the user scrolls the scroll bar

Из чего следует, что если я задам Range в 200, то и Position можно будет задать в этом промежутке. Однако, при выполнении следующего кода:

```
Image->Width= Image->172 // это TImage, лежащий внутри ScrollBox
Image->Height= Image->172;

VertScrollBar->Range= Image->Height; // Уснанавливаю Range скроллбаров скроллбокса
HorzScrollBar->Range=Image->Width;

ScrollBox->VertScrollBar->Position=100;
ScrollBox->HorzScrollBar->Position=100;
```

И вот здесь позиции скролл баров устанавливаются в 37, а не в 100 и оказываются на конце своих интервалов. Т.е их интервал на самом деле от 0 до 37. Почему?

Comment: А не задавалось или не осталось ли отдельно дефолтное поле ThumbLength или подобное? Размер ползунка как раз может быть замешан в этом.